# Pyqt4 linking one window to another via buttons

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am new in pyqt I  have made three files IMC21.py, idleclick.py and popup.py.

The last is a separate window and in each window we have some buttons which are used to move into another window. But while hiding the previous windows I'm facing problems and am not able to run my programs.

These are the errors:

> File "IMC21.py", line 10, in
>
> from idleClick1 import Ui_NewWindow   File "/home/aman/Downloads/PYQT/idleClick1.py", line 11, in
>
> from PopUp1 import Ui_homeWindow   File "/home/aman/Downloads/PYQT/PopUp1.py", line 10, in
>
> from IMC21 import Ui_MainWindow   File "/home/aman/Downloads/PYQT/IMC21.py", line 10, in
>
> from idleClick1 import Ui_NewWindow ImportError: cannot import name Ui_NewWindow

Please help me to sought out these errors.
Link of my programs:

https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1Lop4OQtFAAwto3tiN-XExJWqGXzZ-mjD

Comment: You should post the relevant code in the question instead of a link to an external site, because links can become broken and then this question would be useless to new users. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Sir I have updated the sharing settings of my drive link.Know you can access it and please let me know the solution.Thank  you sir

Comment: The code should be in the question, not linked.

Comment: @devius  when from popup1.py and idleclick1.py ,i commented the lines "from IMC21 import Ui_MainWindow" & "NewWindow.hide() " I am able to open the second window idleclick1.py by hiding IMC21.py on clicking idle button and also able to open third window popup1.py on clicking the save button but not able to hide the previous window idleclick.py. As in this i commented hide function but when not hiding it, it generates error. In popup1.py window the line that i have commented is linking to our first window IMC21.py when i uncomment it, it generates error. Please help me .